# ASP.net MVC4 WebApi route with file-name in it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm trying to get the following (and similar) urls to work in my ASP.net MVC4/WebApi project:

```
http://127.0.0.1:81/api/nav/SpotiFire/SpotiFire.dll
```

The route responsible for this url looks like this:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "Nav",
            routeTemplate: "api/nav/{project}/{assembly}/{namespace}/{type}/{member}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Nav", assembly = RouteParameter.Optional, @namespace = RouteParameter.Optional, type = RouteParameter.Optional, member = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

It works just fine if I remove the . in the file-name, or if I add a slash behind the URL, but that also means I can't use the `Url.Route`-methods etc. The error I get is a generic 404-error (image below).

[image]

I've tried adding `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />` to my web.config, and I've also tried adding

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
  <buildProviders>
    <remove extension=".dll"/>
    <remove extension=".exe"/>
  </buildProviders>
</compilation>
```

And none of it seems to work. So my question is basically, how can I get this URL to work, and map correctly?

Comment: Only the last portion of a route can be optional. In the example you have shown you have made all the route parameters except project optional which obviously is not possible. Also in the url you have shown you are missing `namespace` and `type` portions of the url. Only the `member` portion can be optional because it is defined at the end of the route.

Comment: This is not true, and it's proven to work without problems. You can have as many parts optional as you want to. For instance, even before the change I just made in my answer, the url `/api/nav/SpotiFire` worked as a charm.

Comment: This also works for ASP.NET Web API 2.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You could add the following handler to the `<handlers>` section of your `<system.webServer>`:

```
<add 
    name="ManagedDllExtension" 
    path="api/nav/*/*.dll" 
    verb="GET" 
    type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" 
    preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" 
/>
```

This will make all requests containing `.dll` be served through the managed pipeline. Also notice how I have limited them only to the GET verb to limit the performance impact.

Comment: Brilliant, thought shouldn't this `<add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />` cover that already? I'm not sure what's covered by "*.".

Comment: No, it's not covering it. You need to specify the extension. If there's an extension in the url, IIS will take over thinking that it is a static file.

Comment: This is such a fantastic answer.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, what if we use this: `path="*.*"`? It works, for any kind of file, but I'm wondering if it can create side problems. Kind regards.

Answer (score 13):

Found it. What's needed is this (and maybe some of the things I've added above in the original post):

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you adding this because it will have a bad side effect => all requests will now go through the managed pipeline which will have a negative impact on the performance of your application.

Comment: True, I might find a better solution in time, however, already more than 90% of requests are managed requests, so I don't think the performance-hit will be too big at all... The only thing that isn't loaded through the managed pipeline are images, and I have about 2 of them on my entire page...

Comment: Checkout my answer for the correct way to make this without activating the `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"`.

Answer (score 5):

My trade off was to append `/end` to the end of route. `.`'s are ignored before the last `/`.

The equivalent URL would be *http://127.0.0.1:81/api/nav/SpotiFire/SpotiFire.dll/end*.

The benefit being that you don't get a performance hit on your assets.

Comment: This worked for me and was the simplest solution, though I just added a `/` at the end.