# Web API - Routing requests for endpoints with an extension (.xml)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am trying to route a request

> /api/someName.xml?param1=123

I tried routing all requests to my default controller - MyController and it will route a call like:

> http://localhost:54865/api/**someName**?param1=312.1232&param2=13.321

but I need not route a request like

> http://localhost:54865/api/**someName.xml**?param1=312.1232&param2=13.321

I am not able to do that right now with the following Route map entry:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{*uri}",
                defaults: new { controller = "MyController"});
```

how can I allow endpoints with extension (someName.xml) to be routed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at [ASP.net MVC4 WebApi route with file-name in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664488/asp-net-mvc4-webapi-route-with-file-name-in-it)

Solution - in the Web.config file, just add the following xml attribute under the `<handlers>` section of `<system.webServer>`

```
<add
          name="ManagedDllExtension"
          path="api/*.xml"
          verb="GET"
          type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
          preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
```

Comment: Not that this has any inpact on the code, but I would probably change the name to MangedXmlExtention in this case.