# C# WebAPI catch all url not catching urls with extensions

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing, webapi

I have an endpoint that I want to catch all POSTs regardless of what the url is.

Currently I have:

```
public class ProxyController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("{*url}")]
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post()
        {
             .............
```

This works great for urls like 'http://localhost:64578/SomeRoute'

and the endpoint gets hit.

But as soon as I add an extension eg.

'http://localhost:64578/SomeRoute.svc'

The endpoint doesn't get hit.

It will however hit 'http://localhost:64578/SomeRoute.svc/'

but I really need the former.

My route setup looks like:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            var container = StructureMapIoC.GetStructureMapContainer();
            ConfigStructureMapContainer(config, container);

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

Is anyone able to explain why and suggest how to fix?

Comment: Do you actually need the POST data? Or is this basically a need for a catch-all 404 handler?

Answer (score 0):

This should catch all routes with all extensions `{*.*}`

Edit: Tested some options from [ASP.net MVC4 WebApi route with file-name in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664488/asp-net-mvc4-webapi-route-with-file-name-in-it).

- Combination of `[Route("{*.*}")]` and

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ManagedFilesExtension" path="*.*" verb="POST" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

does work, but not for all extensions (*.svc doesn't work for example)

- Same for `[Route("{*.*}")]` +

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

but this option if worse for performance since is catches all request types (first one only catches POST)

Comment: Tested some solutions and updated the answer. This should help